# Unity Destroying Instantiated clone stops instantiating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have this code, to Instantiate a sprite

**AppleSpawner.cs**

```
public class appleSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
  private int isRunning = 1;
  private readonly int[] positions = { -10, -5, 0, 5, 10 }; 
  public int NumberOfSeconds;
  System.Random rand = new System.Random();

  private void Update()
  {
      if (isRunning == 1) StartCoroutine(Wait());    
  }

  public IEnumerator Wait()
  {
      int randomX = rand.Next(5);
      isRunning = 0;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(NumberOfSeconds);
      Instantiate(this, new Vector3(randomX, 5, 0), transform.rotation);

  }
}
```

Here comes question#1: Is this even the best/easiest way to wait X seconds between instantiating a new copy?

I have a character too, with an oncollision event, if it collides with one of the copys, it should destroy it. This works fine, problem is, if I collide with the **last generated copy**, it destroys it and then the copys **stop spawning**.

**character.cs**

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
  if (collision.gameObject.tag == "apple")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        points++;
        text.text = "points: " + pont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Each of the objects your player collides with, appears to be `AppleSpawner`, is the source of your instantiations and what `Character` is ultimately destroying. If you want to continue spawning objects, you could instantiate another class, named `Apple`, which the collision will destroy instead.

Comment: I don't really understant this (beginner in Unity) I'm destroying a new copied sprite of the apple spite, don't I?

Comment: In this case, ApplySpawner is spawning instances of itself, so when the last instance is destoryed, it can't spawn itself again. Changing `Instantiate(this, new Vector3(randomX, 5, 0), transform.rotation);` to something other than `this` should solve your spawning issue when all sprites have been destroyed.

Comment: You are destroying new copied sprites, but those copies are `AppleSpawner`, if they were `Apple` or some other GameObject, `AppleSpawner` won't be affected by `Apple` collisions

Comment: This might be a better option than a hardcoded Gameobject, you could have a `public GameObject gObjToSpawn` and pass in your sprite gameobject to be generated and use that in `Instantiate(gObjToSpawn, new Vector3(randomX, 5, 0), transform.rotation);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Create a new empty game object called "Applespawner". Put Applespawner.cs in it.

Change this

```
private void Update()
{
    if (isRunning == 1) StartCoroutine(Wait());    
}
```

to

```
private void Start()
{
    if (isRunning == 1) StartCoroutine(Wait());    
}
```

You set `isRunning` to 0 in `Awake()`, makes no sense to call IEnumerator in Update function.

You should add this line to your Applespawner.cs `public GameObject Apple = null;`

And attach your Apple prefab to Applespawner.cs's Apple slot in the editor. If you do not know how to make a prefab, google it.

I think there are 2 best way that you can initiate gameobject every X seconds.

- First way

  ```
  public IEnumerator Wait()
  {
      while(true){
          yield return new Waitforseconds(X seconds);
          Instantiate an object.
      }
   }
  ```
- second way

  ```
  float spawnRate = 1f;
  float nextTimeToSpawn = 0;

  private void Update()
  {
      if (Time.time >= nextTimeToSpawn){

          nextTimeToSpawn = Time.time + 1f / spawnRate;
          //Spawn something
      }    
  }
  ```

I personally prefer the second way. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

#### Do not mix different responsibilities in one class.

It makes your code bug-prone and increasingly harder to maintain as that one class grows bigger. You should have a spawner, which spawns apples, and an apple prefab with collider. Two different scripts.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
    private static readonly int[] positions = { -10, -5, 0, 5, 10 }; 
    public int NumberOfSeconds;
    private System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    public GameObject Prefab;

    public IEnumerator Start() {
        while (true) {
            int randomX = positions[rand.Next(5)];
            Instantiate(Prefab, new Vector3(randomX, 5, 0), transform.rotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(NumberOfSeconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Objects with that component should not have colliders or sprite in your case, so they will never be destroyed on collision with player. Prefabs which are spawned are your regular apples which player collect or avoid.

Since the spawner does not produce another spawners, we put spawn logic in a loop.

You probably want random position from array instead of raw random number, so I fixed it.

#### Generalize.

Now your spawner does the only function - spawning. It's no longer bound to apples, so you can spawn carrots with another spawner. The logic stays the same.

#### What is this magic in `Start`?

You can make `Start` a coroutine. It works just like any other coroutine: runs until `yield return`, `yield break` or end of function. The latter two end the coroutine, otherwise it waits, and then continues running. It's better then flags in `Update` controlling coroutines.

If you need a script that should run every frame, then use `Update`.